# AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() in the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, root, sudo, mac-app-store

For ages I have been working on a file manager and I would love to make it available in the Mac App Store.

I was under the impression that AEWP is not allowed in the Mac App Store.

iirc. I read some time ago that a backup app was accepted in the Mac App Store which uses AEWP, but I cannot remember the name.

What apps in the Mac App Store uses AEWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed various file managers via the Mac App Store and only [Transmit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/transmit/id403388562?mt=12) is able to show an AEWP.

[image: Screenshot of Transmits AEWP]

I'm still curious to if there are other apps in Mac App Store that uses AEWP?